# Android Alarm Manager setting strange schedule

Tags: android

I am having a problem with trying to schedule my service to run every so often. I have gotten my service to start on boot, but for what ever reason when the schedule starts is starts the service way to many times.

```
public class PPPService extends Service {

  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
      //TODO do something useful
      Log.v("TEST", "Service started");

      // Schedule the alarm!
     PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
      AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, mAlarmSender);  

      this.stopSelf();
      }
}
```

**Resolved:** This was resolved by creating a Scheduler instead of having my service schedule itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending in the PendingIntent the context of your service that will be killed very soon along with the intent which started it. I guess this can be quite unpredictable. Try getting the pending intent like this:

```
mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PPPService.class), 0);
```

Comment: hmmm... still getting multiple starts. As far as I can tell the results are the same. I wonder why it would do this to begin with.

Comment: Should I just create another service to hand this off to?

Comment: Thank you for your help. your response made me realize I needed a scheduler instead of having my service schedule itself.